# Split number using a maximum amount?

Tags: c#

I'm a bit stuck in this:

Let's say I want to have 45 items of something, but the maximum stack I can have of that item is 10.
So I want a collection that returns me [10, 10, 10, 10, 5] based on that.

This is what I currently have. (yes, I have to use unsigned int16 for my project, but it doesn't matter if your example is regular integer).

```
ushort Ceiling = (ushort)Math.Ceiling((double)Amount / (double)MaxStackSize);
ushort[] Sizes = new ushort[Ceiling];

for (ushort i = 0; i < Ceiling; i++)
{
    if (Amount != MaxStackSize && i == Ceiling - 1)
    {
        Sizes[i] = (ushort)(Amount % MaxStackSize);
    }
    else
    {
        Sizes[i] = MaxStackSize;
    }
}
```

It works to a certain degree, but sometimes the module will return 0. (for example 10 % 10 or 30 % 10).
Or maybe there's a better way to do this instead of what I'm doing. I'll appreciate the help!

Comment: Are `Amount` and `MaxStackSize` are also of type `ushort`?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Yeah! But it honestly doesn't matter much, I can cast them :)

Comment: If you do an "integer division", you'll get the number of "full" bins you'll get. Then, the last bin will contain the "rest" no need for loops. For example: 45/10 (both integer) = 4. 4*10=40; 45-40 = 5 => result is [10, 10, 10, 10, 5].

Comment: Do you want to split the number 45 into an array of numbers 10,10,10,10,5, or do you want to split a collection of 45 items into a collection of collections such that you have four collections 10 big and one collection 5 big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `LINQ` the next approach can be used:

```
using System.Linq;


ushort Amount = 45;
ushort MaxStackSize = 10;

ushort div = (ushort) (Amount / MaxStackSize);
ushort mod = (ushort) (Amount % MaxStackSize);

ushort[] Sizes;

if (mod == 0)
{
    Sizes = Enumerable.Repeat<ushort>(MaxStackSize, div).ToArray();
}
else
{
    Sizes = Enumerable.Repeat<ushort>(MaxStackSize, div).Concat(new ushort[] {mod}).ToArray();
}
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JKBpjf).

---

**UPDATE:**

@Gimly pointed out in the comment:

> I wouldn't even put the else, the first part in both your if and else
>   is repeated, so you could always do the first part and only do the
>   Concat part in the if (reversed).

Here is a modified solution, using @Gimly's hint:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


ushort Amount = 45;
ushort MaxStackSize = 10;

ushort div = (ushort) (Amount / MaxStackSize);
ushort mod = (ushort) (Amount % MaxStackSize);

IEnumerable<ushort> result = Enumerable.Repeat<ushort>(MaxStackSize, div);

if (mod != 0)
    result = result.Concat(new ushort[] {mod});

ushort[] Sizes = result.ToArray();
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Px2s5I).

Comment: I wouldn't even put the `else`, the first part in both your if and else is repeated, so you could always do the first part and only do the `Concat` part in the if (reversed).

Comment: @Gimly Thank you. Very good point. I also added a solution, that used your hint.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same as Turdashev answer but using regular loops. At least for me, it's easier to understand the idea this way. It's important to ouline edgecases which potentally can make your problem more difficul. Do you need to validate the amount, the maxSize? Is it possible to have more packages than it's allowed to return (For example maxSize is 2 items per package and you have 1 million items, is that OK?) and stuff like that. Other than that here is the loop variant:

```
    public static List<int> Packages(int amount)
    {
        var packages = new List<int>();
        var maxSize = 10;

        if (amount <= maxSize)
        {
            packages.Add(amount);
            return packages;
        }

        var fullPackages = amount / maxSize;
        var rest = amount - (fullPackages * maxSize);

        for (var i = 0; i < fullPackages; i++)
        {
            packages.Add(maxSize);
        }

        if (rest > 0)
        {
            packages.Add(rest);
        }

        return packages;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit picky about using var (but that's just me anyway haha) but would this solution be faster than the one above considering this one uses regular loops?

Comment: No. It won't. I personally consider it more human-readable and since the algorithm itself is not that difficult I wanted to point out that there might be other things that the OP should take into consideration especially the case when you may overflow the max number of packages if such thing exist. Also, in a practical way this could be actually faster because if 90% of the time the `amount <= maxSize` you won't even execute the heavier logic. Other than that - no, it's more of a personal preference.

Comment: Regarding the *var* keyword you can look at MSDN code convention -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions not that it's the source of all truth but I pretty much support this particular rule for when to use/not use *var*